# Why does Apache print the contents of my PHP files instead of passing them to PHP-FPM?

Tags: php, apache

I have the below configuration file under `sites-enabled`. I'm using `mod_proxy_fcgi`.

```
ServerName local.dev

<Directory /var/www/local/>
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerAlias *.local.*.com
    SetEnv CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT ENV_DOCKER

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/local/%3/trunk/%3+-%1/site/www

    ProxyPassMatch "^/var/www/local/(.*/trunk/.*/site/www/.*\.php.*)$" "fcgi://php:9000/var/www/local/$1"

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    LogLevel debug

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerAlias local.*.com
    SetEnv CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT ENV_DOCKER

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/local/%2/trunk/%2+/site/www

    ProxyPassMatch "^/var/www/local/(.*/trunk/.*/site/www/.*\.php.*)$" "fcgi://php:9000/var/www/local/$1"

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    LogLevel debug

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: hmmm ... on the ProxyPassMatch , i use un-quoted strings (not certain it matters) , and instead of `fcgi://php:9000/blabla`, i configured `fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/blabla` ... assuming your php-fpm runs on localhost of course.

Comment: My php-fpm isn't running on localhost - it's running inside of a docker container named `php`. I tried without the quotes, too, but no dice. The official examples in the documentation for mod_proxy_fcgi have quotes.

Comment: and 'php' is resolvable (DNS-wise) , from the box running the apache here. Also, surely you have a `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php ` somewhere in your apache mime config.

Comment: Aha! Yes, php is resolvable DNS-wise, but I don't think I have that in my Apache mime config.

Comment: I tried adding that to a config file which is getting included, but it didn't seem to have any affect. Any other ideas?

Comment: well, the only way i can replicate that is if I not load module php5_module. But then, only php embedded in html gets 'displayed' instead of 'executed'. The GET requests to a .php are still pushed over to the running php-fpm processes via the ProxyPassMatch directive. One last comment : you may be editing the wrong files, or editing the right files that are not deployed, or any other obscure thing. Try to make an obvious 'error' to your config files, push them, and see if it manifests itself.

Comment: I can verify the file is being included - I added some bogus lines to the config and it prevents Apache from starting. What exactly do you mean when you mention the php5_module? Are you talking about mod_php or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that I just needed a `SetHandler` directive in my Apache config.

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://php:9000"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you may need the following:

```
$ sudo a2enmod cgi
[sudo] password for foo: 
Your MPM seems to be threaded. Selecting cgid instead of cgi.
Enabling module cgid.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:

  systemctl restart apache2
```

This was frustrating for me to find after spending FAR too long comparing the configurations of the old machine (which works, and was set up by me 6 years ago) and the new machine.

This is on Ubuntu 22, a system I'm just now setting up.